# Concatenate ids based off of same Name in Entity Framework/Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, concatenation

Given a list of states that have location ids:

```
location_id    name
-----------    ----
1546           Arizona
8543           Arizona
7894           Arizona
8456           Maine
8354           New York
1268           New York
```

I am selecting from this table as such

```
var query = (from s in db.Locations
             //A bunch of joins and where clause to filter list
             select new { s.location_id, s.name });
```

I would like to get a list that contains

```
    location_id    name
    -----------    ----
    1546,8543,7894 Arizona
    8456           Maine
    8354,1268      New York
```

How would I go about this?

I read that entity framework can't translate String.Join so I would have to call ToList() first and then select from that list joining the location ids but when I do it I get the same list that I started with.

How can I get the result I am looking for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group:

```
var query2 = from l in query.AsEnumerable()
             group l by l.name into g
             select new { 
                 location_id = String.Join(",", g.Select(x=>x.location_id.ToString())),
                 name = g.Key
             };
```

I believe you'll need the `AsEnumerable()` call because you cannot translate a `String.Join` into SQL. You can of course `ToList()` instead if you prefer to eagerly load. However, as @Servy points out, you should do the grouping on the database side:

```
var query2 = from g in query.GroupBy(l => l.name).AsEnumerable()
             select new { 
                 location_id = String.Join(",", g.Select(x=>x.location_id.ToString())),
                 name = g.Key
             };
```

Comment: The grouping *should* be done on the DB side though, not on the application side.  Only the joining should be done on the application side.

Comment: How would I group by on the DB side? In SQL doesn't everything in the select need to be in the group by clause. I'm trying the method posted right now and will post back.

Comment: @Servy Is this actually possible? You're not returning unique grouped values (in SQL terms, you are returning LOCATION_ID and NAME but grouping only by NAME without an aggregate on LOCATION_ID)

Comment: @lc. In a word, yes.  It won't translate 1:1 to a SQL group by, but it can be done.

Comment: @Servy Interesting, I didn't know the framework was that smart. I would suppose it enforces an order and can then do the grouping in a single pass as data comes in? I'm curious the exact query that comes out.

Comment: Servy, do you have an example you could type up for us?

Comment: Your edit didn't work for me, but the original one you have there did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially all you're doing here is a `GroupBy`.  You can then manipulate the results of the group in linq to objects, rather than the query, after you've pulled the results:

```
var dbquery = (from s in db.Locations
                //A bunch of joins and where clause to filter list
                group s.location_id by s.name into locations
                select new { locations, name = locations.Key });

var query = dbquery.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(group => new
    {
        name = group.name,
        locations = string.Join(",", group.locations)
    });
```

Comment: I tried this but my main database query uses Distinct to get back all the locations and that doesn't work with your method. If I remove distinct I get the correct result, but it delays longer as it seems to bring back ALL the repeat locations THEN group. I like the idea of keeping it in the database I'm just having trouble doing it.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 Without knowing specifically what you're doing with the locations I couldn't say how to get it to work properly.  Based on your question, you need to have all of the locations provided in the output, you're just arranging them a certain way, so obviously you'll be pulling back all of the locations from the DB.  If you don't want to do that, you can't have them all in the output.

Comment: The only thing really different then what I wrote is the database table we have due to the inner joins returns multiple records for the same values. For example Arizona at 1546 might appear 200 times but my distinct makes only the three different Arizona values show.

Comment: So maybe three queries? The first to do mine with the distinct, the next yours with the grouping, and the third the client side location join?

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 As I said, without knowing what you're *actually* trying to do, I couldn't say.